# How to trigger a C# application at a certain time?

Tags: c#, sql, triggers, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a C# programm currently implemented as a *Windows Forms* application. It can easily be rewritten to a console application.

This application fetches data from a certain source and writes it to *SQL* tables.
I also have a machine with *Windows Server 2008 R2* on it.

I wonder would it be possible to somehow deploy my application on the abovementioned machine in a way that would trigger the execution of my programm on a certain weekday at a certain time, every week?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had given one solution for this type of situation. Instead of writing similar answer I am just pointing you to the answer -

[Periodic execution of particular code in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24135052/periodic-execution-of-particular-code-in-c-sharp?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 6):

One approach would to be write a Window Service instead, upon startup you can register a timer, or event to fire at a particular time to do your processing.

You can read more about writing windows services [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can [Schedule a task](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/schedule-task) in Windows Scheduler