# window c# application to run as task scheduler

Tags: c#

I have a windows applcaition with one button and  want that to be automated i.e runas task scheduler instead of manually pressing button. I get this error while I do this. Index was outside the bounds of the array.

here is my code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Process1();
}

public void Process1()
{
    dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    dialog.Title = "Save file as...";
    dialog.Filter = "XML Files (*.xml)|*.xml";
    dialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
    //dialog.InitialDirectory = @"v:\";

    //blah blah blah...... code here..
}
```

p**rogram.cs**

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    //Application.Run(new Form1());
    Form1 form = new Form1();

    String[] arguments = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
    if (arguments.Count() >= 1) 
    {
        // next line shows up the error
        Int16 valueArgument = Int16.Parse(arguments[1]);// <--- 

        switch(valueArgument)
        {
            case 1 :
                form.Process1();
                break;      
        }
    }
    // ...
```

this was working for  on another application  with 11 buttons on it. here I have only one button to run but failed.

Comment: What is the error you are seeing? Error log?

Answer (score 1):

If you have 1 argument then `arguments[1]` won't exist. To get the first argument use `arguments[0]`.

As @ActiveHigh points out in the comments, the first argument will always be the file name of the executing program (see the Remarks section in the [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx) documentation.

This implies you aren't passing a command line parameter. It also suggests you should update your argument count check to be > 1 rather than >= 1 as this condition will always be true.

Comment: The first argument is always the file executing. So even if he has one argument it will start from position 1, so that part is correct.

Comment: @ActiveHigh Interesting - wasn't aware of that. Will update the answer.

Comment: Hi ActiveHigh .. can you help me how to pass the arguments if you have only one argument in switch stament

Comment: @shruthi Posted an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your program has numerous errors. I have pointed out as much as I can -

1. `Windows Form  Application` does not work as same as `Console Application`. For console as soon as you exit Main, the program will exit. This is what happens now in your code. For windows form application to run indefinitely, you have to take help from `Application.Run`, which I see you have commented out. So you program will run and exit.
2. The second error is -

   `String[] arguments = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();`,  `arguments` is an array so it does not have `Count()` method. You should use `arguments.Length`
3. You have to call `ShowDialog` to show the dialog.

If you want something working you have to at least fix this issues. Better instead of using the main method, pass all parameter to form and then do whatever you want in the form -

The Form -

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Shown += (s, e) => {
            String[] arguments = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
            if (arguments.Length > 1)
            {
                Int16 valueArgument = Int16.Parse(arguments[1]); 
                switch (valueArgument)
                {
                    case 1:
                        this.Process1();
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Process1();
    }

    public void Process1()
    {
        var dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        dialog.Title = "Save file as...";
        dialog.Filter = "XML Files (*.xml)|*.xml";
        dialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
        dialog.ShowDialog(this);
        //dialog.InitialDirectory = @"v:\";

        //blah blah blah...... code here..
    }
```

And the Program.cs -

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        var handleCreated = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

> Also note that - Application.Run is a blocking call. Any code written
>   after this call will only execute after the called form exited.

Comment: Thanks Active High I get this error when i use this code on class program `The type or namespace name 'ManualResetEvent' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: How do you call this on task scheduler its just normal like passing exe file and the artugment as 1 right

Comment: @shruthi Task Schedular is a difference area of concept. You can view my answer here about Task Schedular - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24135052/periodic-execution-of-particular-code-in-c-sharp?answertab=active#tab-top